# Java Path Filtering for certain extension

Tags: java, arraylist

I'd like recursively search a directory, which might have folders and files inside, for a certain file extension (e.g. .7z).

I use an array in case of a folder, and want to add whatever is a match to an ArrayList.

I add the file matches directly to ArrayList.

Unfortunately, the logic with directory doesn't work right.
Could you help further?

p.s. I'm aware there is an elite solution with Path Filtering with Java 8 but unfortunately can't use it for my project.

```
        //2) go through the extracted directory and look for .7z recursively
        File dir = new File(destDir_PATH);
        File[] dirFiles = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<File> matches2 = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File file : dirFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
                    {
                      public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                      {
                         return name.endsWith(".7z");
                      }
                    });
                    matches2.addAll(Arrays.asList(matches));
                }
                else if (file.isFile()) {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".7z")){
                    matches2.add(file);
                    };
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
```

here, instead of listing the files of the directory you encountered, you again filter the files of your initial ("root") directory. You should change this to

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    File[] matches = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
```